# trying to make a div go to a direction after being dragged

Tags: javascript, html, css

The client should be able to drag the `<div>` with their mouse, and after releasing left-click, it needs to move on its own in this direction from the center of the page. In other words, the client should be able to yeet the `<div>`.

This is My code so far:

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    var xcen = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var ycen = window.innerHeight / 2;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id)) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id).onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
      document.onmousemove = null;
      KickElement();
    }

    function KickElement(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        //if (parseFloat(elmnt.style.left) > window.innerWidth * 0.35) {
            //angle = Math.atan2(e.clientY, e.clientX) * Math.PI / 180, // 30 degrees
            speed = 0.01,
                //deltaX = Math.cos(angle) * speed,
                //deltaY = Math.sin(angle) * speed;
                distanceX = (parseFloat(elmnt.style.left) - xcen) * speed;
            distanceY = (parseFloat(elmnt.style.top) - ycen) * speed;
            setInterval(function () {
                elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop += distanceY) + 'px';
                elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft += distanceX) + 'px';
            }, 1);
        //}
    }
}

document.getElementById("mydiv").style.top = "30%";
    var meh = document.getElementsByClassName("bothrn");
    for (var i = 0; i < meh.length; i++)
        meh[i].style.left = "35%";
```

```css
.bothrn{
    position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    min-width: 30%;
  min-height: 60%;
  cursor: move;
  border-radius: 4vw;
}
```

```html
<h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

<div id="mydiv" class="bothrn">
  <div>Click here to move</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the draggable `<div>` often doesn't actually go in the direction that it was being dragged at. Moreover, and sometimes even goes in another direction in the x or y axis. I'm still learning javascript and all out of ideas, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the div cannot be pushed past the bottom of the page.

Comment: it can... the snippet should be run in a browser window, the snippet doesn't really reflect the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the unit vector of the `(pos1, pos2)` vector after mouse is released and then add the x and y components of that vector to the `<div>` that has to move.

Here is a simple example:

```js
const mousevx = document.querySelector('#mousevx')
const mousevy = document.querySelector('#mousevy')

const box = document.getElementById('box')
box.friction = 0.2
box.speed = 1

dragElement(document.getElementById('box'))

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  let pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event
    e.preventDefault()
    pos3 = e.clientX
    pos4 = e.clientY
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag
    pos1 = 0
    pos2 = 0
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event
    e.preventDefault()
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY
    pos3 = e.clientX
    pos4 = e.clientY

    elmnt.style.left = elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1 + 'px'
    elmnt.style.top = elmnt.offsetTop - pos2 + 'px'
  }

  function closeDragElement(e) {
    document.onmouseup = null
    document.onmousemove = null

    // Get the unit vector
    const mag = Math.sqrt(pos1 ** 2 + pos2 ** 2)
    const uvx = pos1 / mag
    const uvy = pos2 / mag

    // Initial speed
    box.speed = mag / 5

    freeMove(uvx, uvy)
  }

  function freeMove(uvx, uvy) {
    const shiftX = uvx * box.speed
    const shiftY = uvy * box.speed
    mousevx.textContent = 'xV = ' + shiftX.toFixed(2)
    mousevy.textContent = 'yV = ' + shiftY.toFixed(2)
    elmnt.style.top = elmnt.offsetTop - shiftY + 'px'
    elmnt.style.left = elmnt.offsetLeft - shiftX + 'px'

    // Remove this to make it slide forever
    box.speed -= box.friction

    if (box.speed > 0) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => freeMove(uvx, uvy))
    } else {
      mousevx.textContent = 'xV = 0.00'
      mousevy.textContent = 'yV = 0.00'
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.bothrn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  min-width: 30%;
  min-height: 20%;
  cursor: move;
  border-radius: 4vw;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="mousevx"></h2>
<h2 id="mousevy"></h2>
<div id="box" class="bothrn">
  <div>Click here to move</div>
</div>
```

Try experimenting with the `box.friction = 0.2` and `box.speed = mag / 5` to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Great idea! Gonna go over the code and implement it in my site, will let you know how it went